# What material is this jacket made of?

Tags: clothing, material-identification

[image]

You can see it clearly if you zoom on the torn sleeve.
It doesn't look like gabardine or corduroy to me, so I'm a bit confused.

(The screenshot is from 2015's TomorrowLand, in case that helps.)

Comment: Are you trying to replicate it, or just curious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The RPF](http://www.therpf.com/) is a fandom forum for people who craft costumes and props from movies. They usually know where to purchase street clothes used in movies but even they have not been able to identify the manufacturer of this jacket.

[image]

Looking at several pictures (especially the right shoulder in this picture) I'd say it is a light denim. Abbie is correct when she says it looks ribbed. The dotted fabric could be twill but, in this picture it looks ribbed as well, my guess is they are both a light weight denim.

The fray on the sleeve is consistent with frayed denim and to get elastic stitched into the hem, the denim would have to be light weight.

I would have never identified the material in Alexey's picture as denim. It looks so much more like a satin or nylon.

[image]

This picture shows that the jacket has a black and khaki lining.

[image]

This close up would leave me to believe that the aqua hoodie is sleeveless.

Comment: Considering she's wearing four layers of clothes, I'd hope the hoodie was sleeveless! :P It seems like a lot of ribbing for a lightweight denim, though. Have you looked at the closeup of the image in the question? It's completely possible that the wardrobe designer had the jacket made for her... there's also an article I read that mentions they went with a style that's supposed to be reminiscent of her wearing her dad's old clothing, so the jacket could be vintage from the 70s.

Answer (score 2):

The jacket appears to have at least two different types of woven fabric.
The lower lighter khaki color looks like a twill fabric that has a dot overprint.

The upper dark brown fabric over the shoulders looks like a rib.
There may be a hoody underneath, either separate or as part of the jacket. In that case, the hoody fabric will likely be a Jersey knit construction.

There is no way to tell from the photo what the fiber contents of the separate fabrics are, i.e., are the fabrics cotton, wool, polyester, a blend?  That would require testing.

If you are interested either in patching the torn sleeve or replicating the jacket, you will have the best chance of getting close to a match (I doubt very much you'll be able to get an exact match), by taking the jacket to a fabric store and looking for something similar.

If you are trying to describe the jacket for a print ad (for example), this assessment of the fabric construction will be as close as I can get without actually seeing the jacket, but you will also need to tell readers what the fiber content is.  Big differences between the fiber content possibilities as far as look, feel, and care.

Comment: _by taking the jacket to a fabric store and looking for something similar_ that might be hard since it is a movie prop. Do you mean the photo?

Comment: Considering that this jacket is in a collection owned by Disney and is occasionally put on display, I don't think they're going to be repairing it :P https://mousertainment.wordpress.com/2016/05/22/tomorrowland-at-the-el-capitan-theatre-the-costumes-and-props-display/

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about where or what the jacket was other than asking for fabric construction info!  Just trying to be helpful. :-)